# Creating a list of assignments for a school project, but I'm getting a NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, doubly-linked-list

I'm unsure whether or not this has been answered before as I didn't see it under Similar Questions but here goes... For a school project, we have to create a doubly-linked list of `Assignment`s and when I made my `addAssignment(Assignment a)` function, I got a NullPointerException.

In our project, `Assignment`s consist of a `String` for the name of the assignment, `int`s for the number of points earned and the number of points given, a `double` for the percentage grade and a `char` for the letter grade given. `Node`s contain an `Assignment` called "assignment" and "next" and "prev" `Node` references. A `DList` (our doubly-linked list) consists of a "head" and "tail" `Node` at the start.

The code in question is included below. I've included comments detailing where my console gave me error messages.

In class `Assignment`:

```
/**
 * setter
 * @param n = the name of the assignment
 */
public void setName(String n) {
    name = n;
}
```

In class `Node`:

```
/**
 * default constructor
 */
public Node() {
    assignment.setName("");
    assignment.setEarnedPts(0);
    assignment.setTotalPts(0);
    next = prev = null;
}

/**
 * n-argument constructor
 * @param a = assignment
 * @param e = # of earned points
 * @param t = # of total possible points
 * @param n = "next" node
 * @param p = "previous" node
 */
public Node(String name, int e, int t, Node n, Node p) {
    assignment.setName(name); // got an error here
    assignment.setEarnedPts(e);
    assignment.setTotalPts(t);
    assignment.setGrade();
    next = n;
    prev = p;
}
```

Finally, in class `DList`:

```
/**
 * adds an assignment to the list
 * @param a = the assignment
 */
public void addAssignment(Assignment a) {
    // check to see if this is the first node in the list
    Node temp = new Node(a.getName(), a.getEarnedPts(), a.getTotalPts(), tail, head); // got an error here
    if (head == tail) {
        head = temp;
    }
    else { // there are other node(s) in the list
        Node p = head;
        Node q = new Node();
        while (p.getNext() != null) {
            q = p; // set q equal to p, so that q will equal previous node
            p = p.getNext(); // advance p by one node
        }
        p.setNext(temp);
        p.setPrev(q); // ??? ask about this in class later
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't have the entire code, but I suspect, that in your class Node you have a field like this:

```java
class Node{
    Assignment assignment;
```

If that's the case this is your problem: You did not initialize any value to the assignment variable and it is therefore Null. Java does not default initialize like, for example, C++ does. You will have to do it yourself, the constructors for the Node class then look like this:

```java
public Node() {
    assignment = new Assignment();
    assignment.setName("");
    assignment.setEarnedPts(0);
    assignment.setTotalPts(0);
    next = prev = null;
}

public Node(String name, int e, int t, Node n, Node p) {
    assignment = new Assignment();
    assignment.setName(name); // got an error here
    assignment.setEarnedPts(e);
    assignment.setTotalPts(t);
    assignment.setGrade();
    next = n;
    prev = p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your advice worked. Your comment made me curious on the other hand, why does Java not automatically instantiate values like that?

Comment: @gomalley411 because it is not designed to do so (what if there is no new instance needed? e.g. getting some from somewhere else, or if the created instance depends on some condition)